# log4j2 SocketAppender with TLS does not pick up updated certificates

Tags: sockets, ssl, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 SocketAppender with TLS and short-lived certificates. Streaming the logs work fine until the keystore is updated with new key + certificate. The new keystore doesn't seem to be taken into use and after the original certificate expire I get the following error:

```
2020-12-14 08:25:56,958 Thread-2 ERROR Unable to write to stream TLS:log-transformer:5024 for appender Service_Log_Socket org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to TLS:log-transformer:5024 after reestablishing connection for log-transformer/10.102.22.166:5024
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.TcpSocketManager.write(TcpSocketManager.java:237)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.write(OutputStreamManager.java:190)
```

I update the log configuration by swapping between different keystore files followed by LoggerContext.reconfigure() but this has no affect and the socket is not updated.

The appender I use:

```
    <Socket name="Service_Log_Socket_TLS" host="${socketHost}" port="${socketPort}">
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>{"version": "0.2.0", "timestamp": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}", "severity": "${adpLevel}", "service_id": "${serviceId}", "metadata" : {"pod_name": "${podName}", "container_name": "${containerName}", "node_name": "${nodeName}", "namespace": "${namespace}"}, "message": "%r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %maskedmsg%ex"}%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <SSL protocol="TLSv1.2">
        <KeyStore location="/tmp/logcli.jks" password="logclipwd"/>
        <TrustStore location="/tmp/rootcert.jks" password="cacert"/>
      </SSL>
    </Socket>
```

Has anyone managed to update the SocketAppender with new keystore content (key + certificate) or is this perhaps a bug in log4j2?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: No, the problem persists. I'm using a proprietary solution to stream logs for now but want to use log4j as long term solution.

Comment: I also tried to reload it programmatically, but no luck. The Log4J shows error if the new content of the file is corrupted for example, meaning that it tries to load the file, but does not use it if it's a keystore, valid or invalid doesn't matter. Strange!

Comment: A collegue have now created two tickets (bug reports) on Log4j for the issues found:
[LOG4J2-2988](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2988)
[LOG4J2-2989](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2989)